# Stream Video on Flash Media Server

Tags: flash, webcam, flash-media-server

I like stream video on flash media server. I user webcam on flash and publish on the FMS.
When my viewers see this video through FMS video show slowly.

I set the Camera parameters in the flash:

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setMode(760,420,25,true);
cam.setQuality(0,100);
```

I thing if I can Buffer video on the FMS Server for 3sec and then release for distribute to viewers can to solve this issue.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set the buffer time of your client's NetStream. 
`NetStream.bufferTime` and `NetStream.bufferTimeMax`

The docs suggests that you leave bufferTime at 0 for live streaming. What do you mean by "video show slowly"? It's a given that viewers will have a delay of a few seconds.

Documentation for bufferTime and bufferTimeMax:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#bufferTime